# Recursive search for matches in two files

Tags: search, awk, recursive

On the second day, I'm trying to find a solution.
There is a CCC directory; we include subdirectories with numbers 1 2 3 ... 500, in each subdirectory there is a file named A1, containing one word (example) apple banana pear pineapple

```
$ CCC /
/1/A1.txt pear
/2/A1.txt apple
/3/A1.txt banana
/4/A1.txt pineapple
```

The flash BBB directory contains the `ALLIN.txt` file containing the following lines:

```
pear is a very sweet fruit
potatoes are very high in calories
pineapple number 1 for weight loss
raspberries tasty and healthy
everyone likes strawberries !!!
```

So my question is:
how to find and replace occurrences of the first word in a CCC file from a BBB file so that

```
CONCLUSION
$ CCC /
/1/A1.txt pear a very sweet fruit
/4/A1.txt Pineapple No. 1 lose weight
```

and files

```
/ 2
/ 3
delete
```

I had tried:

```
for i in `find ./ -depth -type d ! -wholename './'`
do 
join -j1 -o <${i}(sort A1.txt) <${i}(sort BBB.txt)
done
```

and

```
for i in `find ./ -depth -type d ! -wholename './'`
do
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a)' A1.txt BBB.txt    
perl -lane '$t+=1; $h{$F[0]}=$F[1] if $.==$t; print $F[0]," ",$h{$F[0]} if $t!=$.;$.=0 if eof' $(find -name '*A1.txt')  BBB.txt
```

I'm still learning Linux, so please, be kind to me.

Comment: Your last for-loop seems to be missing a "done". You may like to fix this.

Comment: `pear is a very sweet fruit` and `pear a very sweet fruit` are two different strings. The same for `pineapple number 1 for weight loss` and `Pineapple No. 1 lose weight`. Should they be the same? Or is there another layer of conversion you forgot to mention?

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 0):

## An awk solution

Use this command aginst each file:

`awk -f 2fileMatch.awk BBB/ALLIN.txt someFileNames`

where `someFileNames` is a list of one or more files.

### The awk script

```
FNR == NR {
  replacements[$1] = $0
  next
}

{
  if ( replacements[$1] != "" ) {
    sub( $1, replacements[$1] )
    print > FILENAME
  } else {
    system( "rm " FILENAME )
  }
}
```